# Beta: WebSphere Liberty and tools (September 2016)

Tags: openid, connect, websphere-liberty

September Beta of Liberty introduced a very nifty use case to allow signed JSON Web Token for authentication. This is how I configured openidConnectClient element in server.xml

```
<openidConnectClient id="authRP"
  clientId="authrp"
  inboundPropagation="required"
  issuerIdentifier="https://localhost:9600/oidc/endpoint/OP"
  signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
  trustAliasName="signingcert"
  trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
  >
```

And yet, a GET call without JWT in the request parameter isn't blocked from invoking my application servlet. What am I missing in the configuration? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What features are configured? Is your servlet protected by security constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application servlet itself must be J2EE security role protected, i.e., it must have authorization constraint in web.xml.

Comment: Ah! the basics. Thanks Chunlong.